# python function parameter control

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
def getBooks(self,name):
        query = "SELECT * FROM books"
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        books = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return books
```

I have a function called "getBooks", and this function is actually a combination of 2 functions. one function must work without taking the 'name' parameter, the other must work by taking the 'name' parameter because i have to change the sql template according to the 'name' parameter. how can i provide that?

Comment: What is the error/ behavior that you're getting? can you please share the output!
Also when you say it's a combination of 2 functions, what do you mean and where do you should use the parameter name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a default parameter of name to be None, and then treat the variable according to its type:

```
def getBooks(self,name=None):
    if name is None:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Not sure checking the type is needed, `if name:` would probably suffice

Comment: maybe prefer `if name is None`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is provide a default value `None` for the `name` and check in the query's code if it actually is a `null` value or not:

```
def getBooks(self, name = None):
    query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE name = ? OR ? IS NULL"
    self.cursor.execute(query, (name, name))
    books = self.cursor.fetchall()
    return books
```

or:

```
def getBooks(self, name = None):
    query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE name IS COALESCE(?, name)"
    self.cursor.execute(query, (name,))
    books = self.cursor.fetchall()
    return books
```

In both queries, if you call `getBooks()` then all the rows of the table will be returned.